# Google Drive API Java Client Library Logging

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Does Google Drive API Java Client Log the Outgoing REST - HTTP requests and Incoming REST - HTTP Responses?

This is very essential to debug the API calls to ensure that correct requests and responses are being processed.

Is there a way to turn on Logging to see the Requests and Responses sent to Google via the DRIVE API Calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses java.util.logging.Logger for logging HTTP request and response details, including URL, headers, and content.

Normally logging is managed using a logging.properties file. For example:

```
# Properties file which configures the operation of the JDK logging facility.
# The system will look for this config file to be specified as a system property:
# -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${project_loc:googleplus-simple-cmdline-sample}/logging.properties

# Set up the console handler (uncomment "level" to show more fine-grained messages)
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG

# Set up logging of HTTP requests and responses (uncomment "level" to show)
com.google.api.client.http.level = CONFIG
```

for more information see [logging](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/transport#logging)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will try that.